# .NET Toolbox for Simple Database Apps

Tags: .net, database, user-interface, crud

Over the last few years I've had lots of ideas for small applications that could make life easier for me. During the day I work with large enterprise .NET applications which are of course completely different. I'd like to put together a small collection of technologies that could be used to write simple database CRUD apps along with a front end and was wondering what people use. For example...

- Database: SQLite, SQL CE, XML file ;)
- Data access: Linq2SQL, Massive, Dapper
- Front end: WPF, Winforms
- Patterns: Repository, IoC, etc

Interested to see what people use.

Cheers,
John